# export audit log from azure ad b2c

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-storage-account

I am trying to export Azure Active Directory Audit Logs from B2C Tenant (let's call it Tenant 2) to Azure Storage Account in Tenant 1 (main).

I want to collect any information about users changing passwords, users being created in AD B2C, etc. So far, I've tryed to set the export profile for Activity Logs in Tenant 1, but Activity Logs do not include such a type of information. When I'm looking at the Audit Logs of the Activity Directory in the Tenant 2, I can see all the necessary data, but I can't find a way to set the export.

Is there any way to achieve my goal with Azure's out-of-the-box functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-audit-logs#get-audit-logs-with-the-azure-ad-reporting-api) for the details. Currently it looks like that we can only use Graph API or PowerShell to export the audit logs.